# Converting CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat into UIColor?

Tags: swift

I have an array of colours that look like this...

```
var purpleShades: [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)] = [(186.0/255.0, 85.0/255.0, 211.0/255.0), (147.0/255.0, 112.0/255.0, 219.0/255.0), (138.0/255.0, 43.0/255.0, 226.0/255.0), (148.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 211.0/255.0), (153.0/255.0, 50.0/255.0, 204.0/255.0), (139.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 139.0/255.0)]
```

rather than duplicate code was wondering if anyone could help convert it to UIColor, so I can use it for this piece of code.

```
cell.tintColor = grayShades[Int(index)]
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to end up with: an array of UIColor? — Do you know about `map`?

Answer (score 3):

[This variation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init) of `init` might help you

It accepts `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha` as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice extension to `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(hex: UInt, alpha: CGFloat) {

        var red, green, blue: UInt

        red = ((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16)
        green = ((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8)
        blue = hex & 0x0000FF

        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255, green: CGFloat(green) / 255, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

With that you can write:

```
let purple = UIColor(hex: 0x9932CC, alpha: 1)
```

If you have a lot of colours, another extension on `UIColor` gives you…

```
extension UIColor {
    static let darkOrchid = UIColor(hex: 0x 9932CC, alpha: 1)
    static let darkMagenta = UIColor(hex: 0x 8B008B, alpha: 1)
    static let indigo = UIColor(hex: 0x 4B0082, alpha: 1)
}
```

which allows you to say, for example…

```
cell.tintColor = .darkOrchid
```